# Android php External Database

Tags: php, android, database, web-services, external

I was working on an app that holds Login and Registration activities and it has been working fine for the past week, but now I'm getting different results.

```
    boolean isThere=true;
    StrictMode.enableDefaults();
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> infoToInsert = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    infoToInsert.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",email));
    infoToInsert.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass",pass));
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://itlibrary.byethost24.com/Elcom/IsThere.php"); //YOUR PHP SCRIPT ADDRESS
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(infoToInsert));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Check your Intrent Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    //convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();

        result = sb.toString();
        Toast.makeText(Login.this,result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result " + e.toString());
    }


    if (result.contains("0")){
        isThere=false;
    } else {
        isThere=true;
    }
    return isThere;
```

PHP:

```
<?php

   $con = mysql_connect("sql211.byethost24.com","b24_15070481","********");
   if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   mysql_select_db("b24_15070481_Elcom", $con);
   $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
   $pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];


   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$pass'") or die('Errant query:');

 $row = mysql_num_rows($result);
   print(($row));
   mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: First of all, you really shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions, those are **deprecated** and will be removed in future releases of PHP. And, what's exactly wrong with your code?

Comment: HttpClient is deprecated, you should use HttpUrlConnection instead.

Comment: What do you mean by different result? What was your expection and wwhat do you really get?

Comment: Can you tell me what to change so it would work !
@Aakash

Comment: From what it looks like based on the answer you posted (should be an edit to the OP), you or the host may have added browser-checking (CloudFlare) the site, and since the HTTP Client can't run and follow the JS, it gets stuck on that page.

Comment: I need a full code if you could put it here  ,

Comment: I used to get a value of the Query just a 0 or 1 but now is like

<html><body><h2>Checking your browser <h2><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js"></script>
https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/sphotos-g.ak/hphotos-ak-xpt1/v/t34.0-12/11880293_10207741859533275_1450561961_n.jpg?oh=069ac688119193cf193ae3881c641520&oe=55CE3ED6&gda=1439596366_371b93413eb3a15f4eed6e773acca1d0

Comment: "but now I'm getting different results" such as?